# how to submit spark application from kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Have a look at the image from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html.

[image]

The spark cluster in running **outside kubernetes**. But I am going to run the driver program **inside kubernetes**. The issue is how to let the spark cluster know whether the driver program is.

My kubernetes yaml file:

```
kind: List
apiVersion: v1
items:
- kind: Deployment
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  metadata:
    name: counter-uat
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: spark-driver
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: spark-driver
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: counter-uat
            image: counter:0.1.0
            command: ["/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit", "--class", "Counter", "--master", "spark://spark.uat:7077", "/usr/src/counter.jar"]
- kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: spark-driver
    labels:
      name: spark-driver
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - name: port
      port: 4040
      targetPort: 4040
    selector:
      name: spark-driver
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /172.17.0.8:44117
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable: /172.17.0.8:44117
```

The spark cluster is trying to reach the driver program which ip is 172.17.0.8. 172.17.0.8 may be an internal ip inside kubernetes.

How to fix the problem? How to fix my yaml file? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I added the following two parameters: "--conf", "spark.driver.bindAddress=192.168.42.8", "--conf", "spark.driver.host=0.0.0.0".

But from the log, still trying to reach 172.17.0.8, which is the kubernetes internal pod ip.

**UPDATE**

```
kind: List
apiVersion: v1
items:
- kind: Deployment
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  metadata:
    name: counter-uat
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: counter-driver
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: counter-driver
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: counter-uat
            image: counter:0.1.0
            command: ["/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit", "--class", "Counter", "--master", "spark://spark.uat:7077", "--conf", "spark.driver.bindAddress=192.168.42.8","/usr/src/counter.jar"]

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: counter-driver
  labels:
    name: counter-driver
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: driverport
    port: 42761
    targetPort: 42761
    nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    name: counter-driver
```

Another error:

```
2017-06-23T20:00:07.487656154Z Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 31319)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `spark.driver.host` or `spark.driver.bindAddress` to `"spark.uat"` or `"spark-driver.uat"` or the actual driver host in Spark itself. This is a common issue with these type of distributed projects where the master tells the client where to connect. If you don't specify `spark.driver.host`, it tries to figure out the proper host by itself and just uses the IP it sees. But in this case the IP it sees is an internal Kubernetes IP and might not work properly for the client.

You can also try setting `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` environment variable. It actually has a more promising description of:

> Hostname your Spark program will advertise to other machines.

Comment: `spark.driver.bindAddress` is used to notify spark-cluster where is the application driver?

Comment: Actually `spark.driver.host` seems more promising. You still want it to bind on `0.0.0.0`, but present itself as the hostname.

Comment: Those need to be added on the Spark master, not the job

Comment: how to add to spark master? where is the doc? thanks

Comment: yes, I submitted the application with the mentioned parameters. the spark cluster is still trying to reach the pod ip, not the IP I added as spark.driver.bindAddress

Comment: Reading the question again, I see that the master is running outside and it is the one having the issue. So you need to add these same configuration items (host, port, local) with `--conf` to `spark-submit` and have them point to your exposed service. You also need to expose that port in your deployment configuration which seems to be missing right now.